# Proving for non-holomorphic function $g(z)$ that $\int _ \gamma g(z)dz=0$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Let there be function $g(z)=(z+3)(\overline z-3)e^{z^2}$.

The curve $\gamma$ is a circle with radius $4$ and centered at $z=3$. Prove that  $\int _ \gamma g(z)dz=0$.

Now I can't use Cauchy theorem here, because $g$ isn't holomorphic. It is possible to define $f(z)$ so that $f(z)=g(z)$ for every $z \in \gamma$ and then $\int _ \gamma g(z)dz=\int _ \gamma f(z)dz$. I need to find such $f$ so that it is also holomorphic... Yet I can't really think of anything.

Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: On $\gamma$, you have $$\overline{z}-3 = (\overline{z}-3)\frac{z-3}{z-3} = \frac{\lvert z-3\rvert^2}{z-3} = \frac{16}{z-3}.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that on the $\gamma$ we have
$$
4^2=(\bar z-3)(z-3)
$$
Hence
$$
g(z)=(z+3)\frac{16}{(z-3)}e^{z^2}
$$
on the $\gamma$.
Now use Cauchy's theorem for the function $h(z)=(z+3)\frac{16}{(z-3)}e^{z^2}$.